# Android Layout 2 images horizontally

Tags: java, android, layout, imageview

I need to layout 2 images (longImg and shortImg) horizontally.
The longImg is too long to fit on screen, so really wanting to display a window of it, linked to a SeekBar where the user can scroll the part of the longImg. The container around the longImg must be at a fixed size so the shortImg is not nudged off screen.
What is the best way to do this?

So far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_images_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >      
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/short_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_weight="0.3"         
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:background="@drawable/bg_black"
            android:src="@drawable/shortImg"
         />         

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/long_image"
            android:layout_width="3906dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"  
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/short_image"           
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:src="@drawable/longImg"
        />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems OK in Eclipse graphical layout, but when testing on device, I only get the long image.
How do you force the smallImg to be always present?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your full xml?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you using 'RelativeLayout' in that `android:layout_weight="0.7"` won't work unless its parent is `Linear Layout`. I have changed your xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container_images_layout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/short_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_weight="0.3"         
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:background="@drawable/bg_black"
        android:src="@drawable/shortImg"
     />         

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/long_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"  
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/short_image"           
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:src="@drawable/longImg"
    />
```

Comment: I understand your point about the weighting, but the small image isn't visible. I need to give a priority to the small image on the right. Here the longImg isn't in a fixed container and uses up all its space.

Answer (score -1):

use This :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_images_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/short_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/long_image"
        android:layout_width="3906dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/short_image"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems all you've done is changed the images, so the effects are a step backwards.